# How to get a pop up while trying to open a pdf

Tags: java, itext7

I am trying to get a pop up that pdf is expired if it's creation date is older than some fixed number of days. I am getting the pop-up but after pdf is opened.
I want same as when pdf asks for a password before actually opening the pdf.

```
public class ValidateExpirationPDF {
public static final String DEST = "./resources/GlobalSRG_Homepage_deycpted.pdf";
public static final String SRC = "./resources/GlobalSRG_Homepage.pdf";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    File file = new File(DEST);
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    new ValidateExpirationPDF().validatePdf(DEST);
}

protected void validatePdf(String dest) throws Exception {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(SRC);
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(DEST, new WriterProperties());
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(reader, writer);

    String fileCreationDate = "05-18-2018 17:10:10"; //dummy date
    PdfPage page = pdfDoc.getFirstPage();


if(!validatePdfExpiration(fileCreationDate)) {          
    page.setAdditionalAction(PdfName.O,PdfAction.createJavaScript("var nButton = app.alert({cMsg: 'This PDF Document has been Expired.',cTitle: 'GXG Alert',nIcon: 1, nType: 0 });"
        + "var flag=nButton;"
        + "if (flag == 1) app.execMenuItem('Close');"
        + ""
        + ""));
}else{
    //System.out.println("OUTside :"+validateExpiryDate(fileCreationDate)); 
}

pdfDoc.close();
}


public boolean validatePdfExpiration(String fileCreationDate) throws Exception {

    Boolean validFlag=false;

    Calendar fileCreationCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    fileCreationCalendar.set(2018, 4, 14, 19, 10,10);  //testing purpose set datecalendar.set(year, month, date, hourOfDay, minute, second);
    fileCreationCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,50);
    Date expiryDate = fileCreationCalendar.getTime();

    Calendar currentCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date currentDate = currentCalendar.getTime();

     if(currentDate.before(expiryDate) ||currentDate.equals(expiryDate)) {
         System.out.println("This PDF Document has not been Expired. \n TODAY DATE\t:"+currentDate+"\n"+"EXPIRY DATE\t:"+expiryDate);
         validFlag=true;
        }else{
            System.out.println("This PDF Document has been Expired. \n TODAY DATE\t:"+currentDate+"\n"+"EXPIRY DATE\t:"+expiryDate);
             validFlag=false;
        }

     return validFlag;
}
}
```

Comment: Sorry, suggested an edit without reading the code all the way through, please ignore the retag

Comment: If you want to change the behavior _before_ the PDF is opened, you have to change the PDF viewer, not the PDF document.

Comment: @mkl  what about password protected pdfs, there pop-up appears before pdf opens?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by 'opens'. The pdf viewer has already opened the file, otherwise it wouldn't know it needs a password. That been said, this is the only test done that early, all else you control happens much later.

Comment: correct @mkl, In place of asking for the password, want to show some message on the basis of some calculation. As when it asks for the password behind that pop-up we can't see any content of pdf but as I am using the above-mentioned code we can see the content of pdf above that pop-up appears that is the problem.

Comment: As mentioned above, the encryption test with the follow-up password request is the only special pdf viewer action you can trigger that early. This is built into the viewers. If you want a different calculation and message there, you have to manipulate the viewer.

Comment: @mkl if you can share some resources, will be helpful. thanks.

Comment: It's difficult to find resources for feature that _don't_ exist...